# Custom hook returns Promise but resolves inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise

I'm trying to write a hook which performs a dynamic `import` and returns a `Promise` which resolves when the import has completed.

Here's how I envision it's usage:

```js
await useAfterImport("@custom/path");
```

Here is my faulty attempt:

```js
const useAfterImport = (importPath:string) => {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      import(importPath).then(() => {
        resolve();
      });
    }, [importPath]);
  });
};
```

This attempt fails because the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) have been violated:

> React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks
> must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook
> function. eslintreact-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Is there a way that a hook like this can be written without resorting to using a callback parameter?
I would really like to be able to return a `Promise` so it can be `await`ed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think Promises are the right way to go here:

> Here's how I envision it's usage:

> ```
> await useAfterCustomImport("@custom/path");
> ```

The top level of React component function bodies - the only place hooks can be used - can't have `await` inside of them - they need to render *something* immediately (even if temporarily an empty fragment).

For what you're trying to do, state makes more sense. You could do something like the following:

```
const useAfterCustomImport = (importPath: string) => {
  const [imported, setImported] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    import(importPath)
      .then(() => setImported(true))
      // .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part
  }, []);
  return imported;
};
```

and then

```
const libImported = useAfterCustomImport('some-lib');
return !libImported ? null : (
  <div>
    // JSX that uses the library
  </div>
);
```

This follows the current logic of your current code, which appears to assume that the import contains only side-effects, rather than resolving to useable values. If the module resolves to a useable value, returning both `imported` and the resolve value from the custom hook would be a trivial tweak.

Comment: what is useEffect? kindly give me clue.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=useeffect https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect